# Question about limit and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I have that $u_0>0$ , $u_n=u_n^+-u_n^{\raise{1pt}{-}}$ and $u\mapsto u^{±}$ is continuous

if $u_n\rightarrow u_0$ why we have that $u_n^+\rightarrow u_0$ and $u_n^{\raise{1pt}{-}}\rightarrow 0 $

where $u^+=\max(u,0)$ and $u^-=\max(-u,0)$

Thank you.

Comment: what are $u_n^+$ and $u_n^{\raise{1pt}{-}}$? different sequences? Do we know, for instance, $u_n^+\ge u_n^{\raise{1pt}{-}}$?

Comment: $u^+=\max(u,0)$ and $u^-=\max(-u,0)$

Comment: Ah, that would be good to include in the question.

Comment: so how to do ?please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of convergence, since $u_0\gt0$, there is an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$, we have
$$
\left|u_n-u_0\right|\le u_0\tag{1}
$$
Inequality $(1)$ implies that for all $n\ge N$, $u_n\ge0$. That is, for $n\ge N$, 
$$
u_n^+=u_n\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
u_n^{\raise{1pt}{-}}=0\tag{3}
$$
Now just take limits of $(2)$ and $(3)$.

Comment: $|u_n-u_0|\leq u_0$ why ? , we dont use the continuity of $u\mapsto u^{\pm}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: by the definition of convergence, for *any* $\epsilon\gt0$, there is an $N$ so that for $n\ge N$, $$\left|u_n-u_0\right|\le\epsilon$$ I just chose $\epsilon=u_0$.

Comment: Ohhh ok, and for the continuity because in the paper they precise the use of the continuity

Comment: and the continuity please?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: read my answer carefully and find where I use the continuity of $u\mapsto u^\pm$. In the current question, the continuity of $u\mapsto u^{\raise{1pt}{-}}$ is not relevant. However, because we have $(2)$ and $(3)$, I don't know we actually need to use the continuity of either function.

Comment: where we pass to the limits ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: that would be the only place, but since we have $(2)$ and $(3)$, we simply get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n^+=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=u_0$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n^{\raise{1pt}{-}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0$$ with no reference to the continuity of those functions.

Comment: so we dont use the continuity ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I would say that we have not used their continuity, just their definitions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your assumption that $u_0 > 0$.  If $u_n \to u_0$, then the negative parts of $u_n$ must vanish

Comment: can we see this using $||u_n-u_0||$ ? thank you , and please where is using the continuity of $u\mapsto u^{±}$ ?

Comment: please need your help